# testing for double in visual c++

Tags: c++, .net, windows

I am designing a gui in visual c++ and there is a textbox where user inputs values so a calculation can be performed. How do I validate the input to ensure it can be cast to a *double* value?

Comment: Would checking if each digit is a number and there is zero or one period work? You could design a pretty small regex for that. Alternatively, a stringstream might be useful if you accept input that it does.

Comment: Note that depending upon the locale, the decimal point may be a comma, not a period.

Comment: @Pete, good point. Still easily within a regex though.

Comment: If you use MFC - you may make use of `DDX_Text`. It converts from string to `double`, plus reports an error to the user if the conversion can't be done.

Comment: @Chris: it's not actually... you can easily have a regex for a comma or a period (`[,\.]` or however you'd escape it), but if you accept both then whichever one isn't allowed in your actual locale could still break something unexpectedly later (i.e. when you try to pass the value to a function that attempts actual conversion).

Comment: @TonyDelroy, my bad. Didn't think of that. There's still the vast variety of other options too, it was just a thought.

Comment: @Chris: If you do your own validation, then you'll always have unexpected corner cases where the conversion function rejects something you validated as OK, or vice versa. It's just not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this seems to be a C++ CLI related question and your string from the textbox might be a .NET string, you might want to check the static [Double::Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yd1h1be.aspx#Y0) method. For more portable solutions see the other answers...

Answer (score 3):

In any C++ environment where you have a `std::string` field and wish to check if it contains a `double`, you can simply do something like:

```
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream iss(string_value);
double double_value;
char trailing_junk;
if (iss >> double_value && !(iss >> trailing_junk))
{
    // can use the double...
}
```

As presented, this will reject things like `"1.234q"` or `"-13 what?"` but accept surrounding whitespace e.g. `"  3.9E2  "`.  If you want to reject whitespace, try `#include <iomanip>` then `if (iss >> std::noskipws >> double_value && iss.peek() == EOF) ...`.

You could also do this using old-style C APIs:

```
double double_value;
if (sscanf(string_value.c_str(), "%lf%*c", &double_value) == 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "cast" a string to a double, you can only *convert* it.  [strtod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxsfc1ab%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) function will return a pointer to the character within the string where the conversion stopped, so you can decide what to do further. So you can use this function for conversion AND checking.

Comment: Well, you could [lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html), which would probably be a good idea.

Comment: Unfortunately, strtod() returns 0 if the string could not be converted, making it awkward to distinguish this case from a true zero. Not impossible - you can check where conversion stopped, but beware of whitespace.

Comment: @IanGoldby I suggested (maybe not explicitly enough) that the location of where conversion stopped should be used to decide whether it also succeeeded. Also, it (conveniently) discards leading whitespace.

Comment: @zvbra My comment about whitespace was specific to checking where the conversion stopped - so it was about _trailing_ whitespace.

Comment: @IanGoldby Yeah. In any case, it was unclear from the question whether trailing garbage was allowed or not. In the simplest case, I would just check whether `*endptr==0`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [Boost's lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html), which will throw an exception if the conversion fails.

Comment: Exceptions are not for program flow. You still need to validate the input without causing an exception if invalid inputs are not considered 'exceptional' events.

Answer (score 1):

As stated already, strtod(3) is the answer.

```
bool is_double(const char* str) {
    char *end = 0;
    strtod(str, &end);
    // Is the end point of the double the end of string?
    return end == str + strlen(str);
}
```

---

To address @Ian Goldby's concern, if white space at the end of the sting is a concern, then:

```
bool is_double(const char* str) {
    char *end = 0;
    strtod(str, &end);
    // Is the end point of the double plus white space the end of string?
    return end + strspn(end, " \t\n\r") == str + strlen(str);
}
```

Comment: This example returns false if there is trailing whitespace. Not that there's necessarily anything wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert it to a double value. If it succeeds, the input is valid.

Really, you shouldn't be writing your own rules for deciding what is valid. You'll never get exactly the same rules as the library function that will do the actual conversion.

My favourite recipe is to use sscanf(), and check the return value to ensure exactly one field was converted. For extra credit, use a %n parameter to check that no non-whitespace characters were left over.